# Second moment of Poisson distribution

Tags: probability, combinatorics, intuition

I know that the second moment of Poisson distribution is equal to square of it's rate parameter, and in general it's true for other moments. i can prove it algebraic by Taylor expansion but i'm looking for a intuitive proof. is there any combinatorial consideration at least for second moment?

Comment: The *variance* of a Poisson with parameter $\lambda$ is $\lambda$; its second moment is $\lambda+\lambda^2$. None of them is the "square of its rate parameter" -- was that a typo?

Comment: @Clement C. I think that Dimitarr meant the second **centered** moment.

Comment: @Jean-Marie -- even then, there is no square. The second central moment is the variance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not true. It's true for falling moments, i.e. $E[X(X-1)...(X-i+1)]=\mu^i$
and there is a combinatorial proof:

**Hint**

Prove $$E{X \choose i}=\frac{\mu^i}{i!}$$
instead of the original equation.

Use linearity of expectation.

Consider that you divide $[0,1]$ in $n$ parts of size $\frac{1}{n}$ and select each part with probability $\frac{\mu}{n}$.
(just like Poisson derivation from Binomial distribution.)

So in general there would be $n \choose i$ sets which is selected with probability $\mu^i$.

You can achieve the desired result by a limitation.